# Finding Quartile in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone please let me know how to find the Quartiles like 3rd top quartile and 1st lowest quartile in PostgreSQL.

Have tried using this but the results was not getting correct
https://mode.com/blog/how-to-make-box-and-whisker-plot-sql

Have searched in google also, but the search results are varying and couldn't able to find a perfect answer.

Have created a CTE(final_2) which contains the hourly Average of employees(HA)& the number of items processed(Processed_Count) by employees.Below is one of the attempt made but not resulting the correct answer.Also have confusion in using NTILE() function.

Below is my Query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (Order by f."Processed_Count")   q3,
 PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (Order by f."Processed_Count")   AS q1
FROM final_2 f
```

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: Your query seems to work for me, how did you determine that the answer was incorrect?

Comment: As always: Please add sample data and expected output...